# How to get row key for HBase in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

The mapper task is configured as:

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob("PaperAbout1", scan, InputMapper.class, Text.class, Text.class, job);
```

And the map function header is as follows:

```
protected void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value,
            Mapper<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result, Text, Text>.Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

Any coulmn value that is desired to be retrieved can be retrieved with:

```
String columnValue = Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("ColumnFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("column"))));
```

How can the key of the scanned row be retrieved in the map task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
row.get()
```

will return the byte-array of your key. You would of course have to parse that into the correct datatype(s) you are using as your key with the Bytes.toDatatype() method.